# Selecting raster data by location: for raster and feature class data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, overlay

I have rasters covering certain spots in my environment, I'm looking for a way to extract the values which occur at locations which are defined by a selection of feature layers. I've tried with the SelectLayerbyLocation tool (from ArcMap 10.2 (advanced license)), which seems to do the right thing, but not for this type of data. Does anybody have experience with this or recommendations for tools to use?

Currently it is set up like this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_manager('codist_{0}'.format(FIDa), "INTERSECT", out_flab).save(overlap) #find out if villages overlap with cost layers
```

where 'codist_{0}'.format(FIDa) is the raster (FIDa a list of values), and out_flab is the feature layer extracted from a table using a cursor in previous steps. Ultimately I need to find the minimum value within the rasters at the zones defined by the feature classe (so the values of the raster cannot be altered by this operation)

Comment: Have you looked at the [Zonal Statistics tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000)?

Comment: thank's for the tip. I'd looked into it a while back but looking into with a fresh mind it seems this could work.

Comment: @ChrisW, I've got the zonal stats tool set up and it's working great. the thing is i need to extract only the lowest value from my set, and use it in a subsequent if statement. (ie if miniumvalue <= threshold: do this). do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I can't tell you exactly how to do it as I'm not all that familiar with coding and scripting yet. I'm thinking you just need either a middle step to get the min from all your zones as a variable to then reference in the next statement, or just reference it directly. ZS outputs a raster, so I would think you could use a query in your if statement to run a min function on the output raster in place of the min value itself. Alternatively there is a variant of the tool that outputs a table, which may be easier to access from the script.

Answer (score 2):

The [Zonal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) tool should allow you to 'mix' raster and vector data. You can define your zones based on feature layer polygons to get the statistics of the raster.

There is also the [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/) tool which outputs a table instead of a raster.